# How can i write a switch statement in python using flask framework?

Tags: python, flask, python-3.7

Here is the code

```
switcher = {
    "1": func1(),
    "2": func2(),
    "3": func3(),
    "4": func4(),
    "5": func5(),
    "6": func6(),
    "9": func7(),
    "11": func8(),
    "12":func9(),
    "13": func10()
}

@app.route('/ussdcallback', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def switch(text = request.values.get("text", None)):
    session_id = request.values.get("sessionId", None)
    service_code = request.values.get("serviceCode", None)
    func = switcher.get(text, "none")
    return func()
```

This is the output i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416279+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416279+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416280+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416280+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416280+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416280+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416281+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416281+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416281+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416281+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416282+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416282+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416282+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416282+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416283+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416284+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416285+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416285+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416285+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416285+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416286+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416286+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416286+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/run.py", line 1, in <module>
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416286+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import app
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416286+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 359, in <module>
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416287+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import routes, usrmgt, safeDeposit
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416287+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/routes.py", line 22, in <module>
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416287+00:00 app[web.1]:     "1": radar(),
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416287+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/radar.py", line 161, in radar
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416287+00:00 app[web.1]:     resp = make_response(response, 200)
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416288+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 223, in make_response
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416288+00:00 app[web.1]:     return current_app.make_response(args)
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416288+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416288+00:00 app[web.1]:     return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416288+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416289+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.__local()
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416289+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 52, in _find_app
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416311+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416312+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416312+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416313+00:00 app[web.1]: This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416313+00:00 app[web.1]: to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416313+00:00 app[web.1]: this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416319+00:00 app[web.1]: documentation for more information.
2020-05-19T05:44:17.416716+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-19 05:44:17 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-05-19T05:44:18.050667+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-19 05:44:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-05-19T05:44:18.050834+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-19 05:44:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-05-19T05:44:18.145123+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-05-19T05:44:18.190532+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do! And show us the code that raised the exception. Your code does not fit.

Comment: i am trying to use an alternative switch statement in python to call various function using flask framework. instead of the regular IF ... ELSE statement.

Comment: in summary how can i implement a switch statement in python using flask to run on web

Comment: **Python doesn't have switch statements**. You are trying to use a dict with functions in it. You are *calling* the functions when you put the value in, you need to put the actual function object in there, so don't call them. Then when you *retrieve* the function from the dict, you call it.

Comment: Please can i get an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue lies in the fact that you're actually calling your functions within your `switcher` dict and leaving the results of the calls, instead of them being references to the functions. If you remove the parentheses from your functions in the `switcher` dict, you can then get a reference to the functions themselves, and then call them with `func()` like you do.

```py
switcher = {
    "1": func1,  # No ()
    ...
}
```

Simplistic example of this in action:

```py
>>> def x(): print("test")
...
>>> def y(): print("another test")
...
>>> z = {1:x, 2:y}
>>> z[1]()
test
>>> z[2]()
another test
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - you're using the `request` "thread"-local before there's a request to be handled by Flask, resulting in this error.  You don't want to use thread-local values for defining function argument inputs.

The problem you have here is that you're expecting the default values for function arguments to be evaluated at the function's *call* time, not at its *definition* time:

```
def when_is_this_called(): print("NOW!")

def some_func(an_arg=when_is_this_called()):
    pass

print("Functions defined")
some_func()
```

will print:

```
NOW!
Functions defined
```

instead of:

```
Functions defined
NOW!
```

as you might at first expect.

Instead of:

```
def switch(text = request.values.get("text", None)):
```

get the value in the method's body:

```
def switch():
    text = request.values.get("text", None)
    # ... snip ...
```